# Can't focus in textbox inside jQuery UI modal with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't focus the textbox in a pane which comes on clicking dropdown as shown in image:
[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
          $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
          title: "Upload to: FolderNameGoesHere",
          width: 720,
          height: 450,
          dialogClass: "file-upload-modal",
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Save": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              },
              "Cancel": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });

      // Fix input element click problem
      $('.input-append').click(function (e) {
          //$(this).focus();
          e.stopPropagation();

      });​
```

Here is the live js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5nDUf/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal tries to steal everything away from you :)

```
$('.input-append').click(function (e) {
    //$(this).focus();
    e.stopPropagation();

});​
```

should be

```
// Fix input element click problem
$('.input-append').bind('click mouseup mousedown keypress keydown keyup', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jaMda/